# How to create a new variable with the change of a (dummy) variable over time

Tags: if-statement, stata

I have firm level data for three years (`2015`,  `2016` and `2017`).

I need to know which firms have a change in a dummy variable `ModelJaarrekening` from year `2016` to year `2017` - a dummy that determines if the firm is large (value `2`) or small (value `1`).

In other words, I need to select the firms that have a value for `ModelJaarrekening` of `2` in year `2015` and `2016` but has the value `1` in year `2017`.

The following command does not work:

```
gen dummy=1 if (ModelJaarrekening ==2 & year<2017 & ModelJaarrekening ==1 & year==2017)
```

I think this is because it first executes the first command and deletes the other observations.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There seems a small inconsistency here between 2015 and 2016 in one paragraph and 2016 in another. Please fix that.

Comment: Pieter please read the [Stata tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info) for advice on how to ask Stata-related questions on here. You need to provide example data additionally to code so everyone can replicated the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is legal.

It doesn't delete any observations!

It just doesn't do what you want. The reason is that nothing in your syntax instructs Stata to look beyond each observation separately. So,

```
ModelJaarrekening == 2 & ModelJaarrekening == 1
```

is never going to be true of any observation: a variable can't be 1 and 2 in the same observation. The same kind of problem holds for

```
year < 2017 & year == 2017
```

The result is that your indicator will have values that are all missing.

What you want is more like this. I posit a firm identifier `id`.

```
local foo ModelJaarrekening
egen OK1 = total(`foo' == 2 & year <= 2017), by(id) 
egen OK2 = total(`foo' == 1 & year == 2017), by(id) 
gen wanted = OK1 & OK2
```

Then `OK1` will be 1 or more if and only if there was any value 2 before 2017. `OK2' will be 1 if and only if there was value 1 in 2017 for each firm.

`wanted` will be 1 if and only if both its arguments are non-zero (in this case, negative values are impossible and only positive values count); and 0 otherwise. 
It is thus an indicator (you say dummy) with values 1 and 0.

Indicators that are 1 or missing are less useful in Stata than those that are 1 or 0.

Comment: I need the firms that have value 2 before 2017 and 1 in 2017. But when I change the command it does not work correctly. local foo ModelJaarrekening
egen wanted = total((`foo' == 2 & year <= 2017) | (`foo' == 1 & year == 2017)), by(id) 
replace wanted = wanted >= 1

Comment: You don't say what "doesn't work correctly" means but I guess the problem is with 2 values that are 2 before 2017 and 0 values that are 1 in 2017. Sorry; please see fixed code.